# how to do something after interstitial ad is removed by user

Tags: flutter, admob, firebase-admob

I want to execute a function after the interstitial ad is finished and closed/removed by the user. Is there a way to listen to this event?

I tried to use then after show, but this is not working, it already executes the function after the ad is loaded.

```
_interstitialAd.show().then((_) => {
   foo()
});
```

Comment: that's not an answer, how did you implement it?

Comment: the answer was removed and I don't have access to the code anymore. Sorry